# Simple recurrence relation to yield nearby prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Let $S_1=n>4$, and take

$$S_{i+1}:=S_i+\mathrm{lpf}(S_i-\mathrm{gpf}(S_i))$$

until the value no longer changes, and it seems to yield a prime $n \leq p \leq 2n+1$. Similarly, you can take

$$S_{i+1}:=S_i-\mathrm{lpf}(S_i-\mathrm{gpf}(S_i))$$

and you'll end up with a prime $n/2-1 \leq p \leq n$.

In the equations above, $\mathrm{lpf}$ and $\mathrm{gpf}$ refer to least and greatest prime factors respectively, as in $\mathrm{lpf}(45)=3$ and $\mathrm{gpf}(45)=5$.

I'm curious whether this is provable, particularly if it avoids using Bertrand's postulate or an equivalent principle. But more realistically, I'm curious if this is just a case of my obfuscating some trivial operation.

Comment: I assume the "lpf" function gives the "lowest prime factor" and the "gpf" function gives the "greatest prime factor". Regardless, since these are (as far as I know) not completely standard & well known names, you should make this clear. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking, when $S_1=18$ you wind up with $S_3=23$ as the prime result?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I assume you can see the value no longer changes when $\text{lpf}(S_i - \text{gpf}(S_i)) = 0$. This happens when $S_i = \text{gpf}(S_i)$, which only occurs when $S_i$ is a prime. As such, you're really asking about this eventually occurring, and the bounds where it occurs. Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, I'd meant to add that in the first place. And yes, that's more or less what I'm after. I've empirically verified the bounds I've given for small values of $n$, but don't really have an idea how to take it any further.

Comment: @Ian Yep. $18=2\cdot 3^2 \rightarrow 3\cdot 7 \rightarrow 23 \rightarrow 23 \dots$

Comment: When $S_i$ is odd and composite, then $S_{i+1} = S_i + 2$. When $S_i$ is even and not a power of $2$, then $S_{i+1}$ is odd. When $S_i$ is a power of $2$, then $S_{i+1} = S_i + 2$ is not a power of $2$ (since we have $S_i > 2$). So except for the first or first two steps, you simply increment an odd number by $2$ until you hit a prime.